# No query defined for that name [getAuditTaskById]

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, bpmn

When I tried to start a task using `taskService.start(task.getId(), "krisv");`, I get `No query defined for that name [getAuditTaskById]`. The bpmn file is very similar to the `Evaluation.bpmn` file. My current version of jbpmn is 6.2.

The code snippet is the following:

```
List<TaskSummary> tasks = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("krisv", "en-UK");
if (tasks.size() > 0) {
    TaskSummary task = tasks.get(0);
    System.out.println("Task id: " + task.getId());
    System.out.println("'krisv' completing task " + task.getName() + ": " + task.getDescription());
    System.out.println("Task status: " + task.getStatus().name());
    System.out.println("Potential owners: " + task.getActualOwner().getId());
    taskService.start(task.getId(), "krisv");
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    results.put("performance", "exceeding");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(), "krisv", results);
    System.out.println("Completed task");
} else {
    System.out.println("No tasks!");
}
```

The code above is almost a replicate of the ProcessTest.java file in the sample folder. The ProcessTest.java allows the completion of the tasks, but the exact same code doesn't in my custom java file.

Also, the current task's status is "reserved" if that is of any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is defined in the jbpm-human-task-audit-audit jar, you need that on your classpath:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-audit/src/main/resources/META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml#L40

And you need to make sure this file is referenced in your persistence.xml, like for example here:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-test/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml#L15

Comment: For some reason, the line <mapping-file>META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml</mapping-file> was commented out in persistence.xml. Now it's working! Thank you!